# Style ComboBox Popup to include additional item

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

What is the easiest way to change a `ComboBox`, in WPF, so that the `Popup` has an additional row that could be used to perform a function. For example,

```
--------------------------
| [Button Add New Item]  |
| Item 1                 |
| Item 2                 |
| Item 3                 |
--------------------------
```

I know that the `ComboBox` has the "PART_Popup" that might be able to reuse. But it feels like rewriting the entire style or combo box control is overkill.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to edit the controltemplate, and since you've found PART_Popup, you know where to look.  Drop a button inside the DropDownScrollViewer above the ItemsPresenter.  You might have to play with the template a bit to make it exactly how you want it to look, but you're on the right track.